# Most efficient way to append rows to a Dataframe with unequal columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to append a row (df_row) with every iteration to a parent dataframe (df_all). The parent dataframe has all the possible column values and every iteration produces a row with a unique set of columns which are a subset of the all possible columns. It looks something like this:

`df_all`

initially has all the possible column names:

```
Index A B C D E F G H
```

Iteration 1:

```
df_row1:

Index A C D E F
  ID1 1 2 3 5 1 

df_all=df_all.append(df_row1)
```

Now `df_all` looks as below:

```
df_all:

Index A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H 
  ID1 1  na 2  3  5  1 na na
```

Iteration 2:

`df_row2`:

```
Index A B D F G H
  ID2 0 8 3 5 1 4
df_all=df_all.append(df_row2)
```

Now `df_all` looks as below:

```
df_all:

Index A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H 
  ID1 1  na 2  3  5  1 na na
  ID2 0  8  na 3  na 5  1  4
```

And so on...

However, I have >20000 rows to add and the time taken to add every row is increasing with every new iteration. Is there a way to add this more efficiently within a reasonable amount of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you can build a DataFrame from a list of Series or dicts:

```
In [46]: pd.DataFrame([pd.Series({'A':1,'B':2}), pd.Series({'A':2,'C':3})])
Out[186]: 
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  3.0

In [187]: pd.DataFrame([{'A':1,'B':2}, {'A':2,'C':3}])
Out[187]: 
   A    B    C
0  1  2.0  NaN
1  2  NaN  3.0
```

Therefore, you could build your DataFrame like this:

```
data = []
for n in range(20000):
    df_row = pd.Series(...)
    data.append(df_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is more efficient than calling `df.append` inside the for-loop, since that leads to [quadratic copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/190597).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function!

Try it out as `df_all.merge(df_row, how='outer')`, that should do the job.